# Python: How do I add a Legend with Top 10 Countries in my Bokeh GeoData Plot?

Tags: python, bokeh, geojson, geopandas

I want to add a Legend on the white space on the left of my Wolrd_Data with the top 10 countries and their respective Data. Something like in this plot I found on Reddit --> Link: https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/yog129/europes_impressive_agriculture_exports_in_2000/
I created my Plot with Bokeh, sadly I am not allowed to post pictures here.

My Code:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256
from bokeh.plotting import figure

json_data='{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "5", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"country": "Kazakhstan", "country_code": "KAZ", "price_game": 11200.0, "price_overall": 11500.0}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[87.35997033076265, 49.21498078062912], [86.59877648310336, 48.549181626980626], [85.7682328633083, 48.45575063739699], [85.72048383987067, 47.452969468773105], [85.16429039911324, 47.0009557155161], [83.18048383986047, 47.33003123635086], [82.45892581576906, 45.539649563166506], [81.9470707539181, 45.31702749285312], [79.96610639844141, 44.91751699480463], [80.86620649610126, 43.18036204688101], [80.1801501809943, 42.92006785742694], [80.2599902688853, 42.34999929459906], [79.64364546094012, 42.49668284765953], [79.14217736197978, 42.85609243424952], [77.65839196158322, 42.96068553320826], [76.00035363149846, 42.98802236589067], [75.63696495962202, 42.87789988867668], [74.21286583852256, 43.29833934180337], [73.64530358266092, 43.09127187760987], [73.48975752146237, 42.50089447689132], [71.8446382994506, 42.8453954127651], [71.18628055205212, 42.70429291439214], [70.96231489449914, 42.266154283205495], [70.3889648782208, 42.08130768489745], [69.07002729683524, 41.38424428971234], [68.63248294462002, 40.66868073176681], [68.25989586779562, 40.6623245305949], [67.98585574735182, 41.13599070898222], [66.71404707221652, 41.1684435084615], [66.51064863471572, 41.987644151368556], [66.02339155463562, 41.99464630794404], [66.09801232286509, 42.997660020513095], [64.90082441595928, 43.72808055274258], [63.18578698105657, 43.650074978198006], [62.01330040878625, 43.50447663021565], [61.05831994003245, 44.40581696225051], [60.23997195825834, 44.78403677019473], [58.68998904809581, 45.50001373959873], [58.50312706892845, 45.586804307632974], [55.928917270741096, 44.99585846615911], [55.96819135928291, 41.30864166926936], [55.45525109235377, 41.25985911718584], [54.75534549339264, 42.043971462566574], [54.07941775901495, 42.32410940202083], [52.944293247291654, 42.11603424739759], [52.50245975119615, 41.78331553808637], [52.44633914572722, 42.027150783855575], [52.692112257707265, 42.44389537207337], [52.50142622255032, 42.7922978785852], [51.342427199108215, 43.132974758469345], [50.89129194520024, 44.03103363705378], [50.339129266161365, 44.284015611338475], [50.30564293803627, 44.609835516938915], [51.278503452363225, 44.51485423438646], [51.31689904155604, 45.2459982366679], [52.16738976421573, 45.40839142514511], [53.0408764992452, 45.25904653582177], [53.220865512917726, 46.234645901059935], [53.042736850807785, 46.85300608986449], [52.04202273947561, 46.80463694923924], [51.191945428274266, 47.048704738953916], [50.03408328634248, 46.60898997658222], [49.10116000000011, 46.399330000000134], [48.59325000000018, 46.56104000000005], [48.694733514201744, 47.07562816017793], [48.05725000000001, 47.74377000000004], [47.31524000000013, 47.7158500000001], [46.46644575377627, 48.39415233010493], [47.04367150247651, 49.152038886097614], [46.75159630716274, 49.35600576435377], [47.54948042174931, 50.454698391311126], [48.57784142435753, 49.87475962991567], [48.70238162618102, 50.60512848571284], [50.76664839051216, 51.6927623561599], [52.32872358583097, 51.718652248738124], [54.532878452376224, 51.02623973245932], [55.71694000000002, 50.62171000000018], [56.77798000000013, 51.043550000000096], [58.363320000000044, 51.06364000000002], [59.642282342370606, 50.545442206415714], [59.93280724471549, 50.842194118851864], [61.337424350840934, 50.79907013610426], [61.58800337102417, 51.272658799843214], [59.967533807215545, 51.9604204372157], [60.92726850774028, 52.44754832621504], [60.73999311711458, 52.71998647725775], [61.699986199800605, 52.97999644633427], [60.978066440683165, 53.66499339457914], [61.43660000000017, 54.00625000000002], [65.17853356309593, 54.35422781027211], [65.66687000000002, 54.60125000000011], [68.16910037625883, 54.97039175070432], [69.06816694527288, 55.38525014914353], [70.86526655465514, 55.169733588270105], [71.18013105660941, 54.13328522400826], [72.22415001820218, 54.376655381886735], [73.5085160663844, 54.0356167669766], [73.42567874542044, 53.489810289109755], [74.38482000000016, 53.54685000000012], [76.89110029491343, 54.49052440044193], [76.52517947785475, 54.17700348572714], [77.80091556184425, 53.404414984747575], [80.03555952344169, 50.86475088154725], [80.56844689323549, 51.38833649352847], [81.94598554883993, 50.81219594990637], [83.38300377801238, 51.069182847693924], [83.93511478061885, 50.88924551045358], [84.41637739455308, 50.311399644565824], [85.11555952346203, 50.11730296487764], [85.54126997268247, 49.69285858824816], [86.82935672398963, 49.82667470966817], [87.35997033076265, 49.21498078062912]]]}}, {"id": "6", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"country": "Uzbekistan", "country_code": "UZB", "price_game": null, "price_overall": null}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[55.96819135928291, 41.30864166926936], [55.928917270741096, 44.99585846615911], [58.50312706892845, 45.586804307632974], [58.68998904809581, 45.50001373959873], [60.23997195825834, 44.78403677019473], [61.05831994003245, 44.40581696225051], [62.01330040878625, 43.50447663021565], [63.18578698105657, 43.650074978198006], [64.90082441595928, 43.72808055274258], [66.09801232286509, 42.997660020513095], [66.02339155463562, 41.99464630794404], [66.51064863471572, 41.987644151368556], [66.71404707221652, 41.1684435084615], [67.98585574735182, 41.13599070898222], [68.25989586779562, 40.6623245305949], [68.63248294462002, 40.66868073176681], [69.07002729683524, 41.38424428971234], [70.3889648782208, 42.08130768489745], [70.96231489449914, 42.266154283205495], [71.25924767444823, 42.16771067968946], [70.42002241402821, 41.51999827734314], [71.1578585142916, 41.14358714452912], [71.87011478057047, 41.392900092121266], [73.05541710804917, 40.866033026689465], [71.77487511585656, 40.14584442805378], [71.01419803252017, 40.24436554621823], [70.60140669137269, 40.21852733007229], [70.45815962105962, 40.49649485937029], [70.66662234892505, 40.960213324541414], [69.32949466337283, 40.72782440852485], [69.0116329283455, 40.08615814875667], [68.53641645698943, 39.53345286717894], [67.70142866401736, 39.58047842056453], [67.44221967964131, 39.140143541005486], [68.17602501818592, 38.901553453113905], [68.39203250516596, 38.15702525486874], [67.82999962755952, 37.144994004864685], [67.07578209825962, 37.35614390720929], [66.51860680528867, 37.36278432875879], [66.54615034370022, 37.97468496352687], [65.2159989765074, 38.4026950139843], [64.17022301621677, 38.892406724598246], [63.51801476426103, 39.36325653742564], [62.374260288345006, 40.05388621679039], [61.88271406438469, 41.084856879229406], [61.54717898951356, 41.266370347654615], [60.465952996670694, 41.22032664648255], [60.083340691981675, 41.425146185871405], [59.976422153569786, 42.22308197689021], [58.62901085799146, 42.75155101172305], [57.78652998233708, 42.17055288346552], [56.932215203687804, 41.826026109375604], [57.0963912290791, 41.32231008561057], [55.96819135928291, 41.30864166926936]]]}}, {"id": "7", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"country": "Papua New Guinea", "country_code": "PNG", "price_game": null, "price_overall": null}, "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[141.00021040259185, -2.60015105551566], [142.73524661679147, -3.28915292726321], [144.58397098203324, -3.861417738463416], [145.27317955950997, -4.373737888205049], [145.8297864117257, -4.876497897972683], [145.981921828393, -5.465609226100043], [147.64807335834757, -6.0836593563108465], [147.89110761941623, -6.614014580922343], [146.97090538959486, -6.721656589386313], [147.19187381407494, -7.388024183790023], [148.08463585834932, -8.044108168167647], [148.73410525939357, -9.104663588093764], [149.30683515848443, -9.07143564213009], [149.26663089416132, -9.514406019736029], [150.03872846903425, -9.684318129111709], [149.7387984560122, -9.872937106977048], [150.80162763895913, -10.293686618697478], [150.6905749859639, -10.582712904505925], [150.02839318257583, -10.652476088099952], [149.78231001200197, -10.393267103723923], [148.92313764871727, -10.280922539921384], [147.913018426708, -10.13044076908745], [147.13544315001218, -9.492443536011983], [146.56788089415056, -8.942554619994155], [146.04848107318492, -8.067414239131281], [144.74416792213805, -7.630128269077446], [143.89708784400966, -7.915330498896296], [143.28637576718432, -8.24549122480908], [143.41391320208066, -8.983068942910982], [142.62843143124417, -9.326820570516524], [142.06825890520025, -9.159595635620022], [141.03385176001382, -9.117892754760483], [141.01705691951895, -5.859021905138071], [141.00021040259185, -2.60015105551566]]], [[[152.64001671774253, -3.659983005389691], [153.0199935243847, -3.9800151505732653], [153.14003787659874, -4.4999834122940925], [152.82729210836828, -4.7664270971909914], [152.63867313050298, -4.176127211120921], [152.40602583232493, -3.7897425268745835], [151.95323693258354, -3.4620622697118155], [151.38427941305002, -3.0354216447101123], [150.66204959533883, -2.741486097833935], [150.93996544820448, -2.500002129734007], [151.47998416565457, -2.779985039891379], [151.8200150901351, -2.9999716121578857], [152.23998945537113, -3.24000864015364], [152.64001671774253, -3.659983005389691]]], [[[151.30139041565388, -5.840728448106752], [150.75444705627666, -6.083762709175431], [150.2411967307538, -6.317753594593028], [149.70996300679332, -6.316513360218025], [148.89006473205046, -6.026040134305404], [148.31893680236067, -5.747142429226166], [148.40182579975686, -5.437755629094717], [149.29841190002082, -5.58374155031926], [149.84556196512722, -5.505503431829368], [149.99625044169028, -5.026101169457654], [150.13975589416486, -5.0013481583898525], [150.23690758687354, -5.532220147324267], [150.80746707580812, -5.455842380396874], [151.08967207255404, -5.113692722192383], [151.6478808941709, -4.757073662946162], [151.53786176982146, -4.167807305521933], [152.1367916200843, -4.14879037843852], [152.33874311748093, -4.312966403829805], [152.3186926617517, -4.867661228050771], [151.98279585185452, -5.478063246282382], [151.45910688700866, -5.560280450058754], [151.30139041565388, -5.840728448106752]]], [[[154.75999067608439, -5.339983819198495], [155.06291792217934, -5.56679168052753], [155.5477462099417, -6.200654799019645], [156.0199654482248, -6.540013929880381], [155.8800256695784, -6.819996840037753], [155.59999108298877, -6.9199907365225215], [155.16699425681514, -6.535931491729322], [154.72919152243838, -5.900828138862195], [154.51411421123964, -5.139117526879986], [154.65250369691728, -5.04243092206189], [154.75999067608439, -5.339983819198495]]]]}}]}'
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=json_data)

palette = Viridis256
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=palette, low=0, high=300000, nan_color = "lightgrey")
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper)

p = figure(plot_height=600,plot_width=950)
p.patches(source=geosource,
         fill_color={"field":"price_game","transform":color_mapper},
         line_color="black")

p.axis.visible = False
p.add_layout(color_bar,"below")
p.outline_line_color = None

output_notebook()
show(p)
```

Comment: Could you please provide parts of you `json_data`. At the moment it is hard to reprocude. FYI: [`p.patches()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.patches) has the keyworsd arguments  `legend_field`, `legend_group`  and `legend_label`. These are made to add to a legend. See also the [legend example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/annotations/legend.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I just edited the post! 
The legend_field/group/label arguments didn't work for me, or at least I don't know how to correctly implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution unsing `geopandas`. The idea is, to loop over each `country` and create a single source for each. This way the `legend_label` can be set individually.

```
import geopandas

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()

json_data='...' # your json string
gdf = geopandas.read_file(json_data)

palette = Viridis256
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=palette, low=0, high=300000, nan_color = "lightgrey")
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper)

p = figure(height=600,width=950)
for n, row in gdf.iterrows():
    p.patches(
        legend_label=row['country_code'],
        source=GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=geopandas.GeoDataFrame([row[["price_game",'geometry']]]).to_json()),
        fill_color={"field":"price_game","transform": color_mapper},
        line_color="black"
    )

p.axis.visible = False
p.add_layout(color_bar,"below")
p.outline_line_color = None

output_notebook()
show(p)
```

### Output

[image: map with legend]

### Comment

Here is a list of packages I used.

- bokeh==3.0.0
- geopandas==0.12.1
- pandas==1.4.3
- Shapely==1.8.5

The result can be different with other versions.

Comment: Hey, thank you so very much!!!! It worked for me now, the plot looks absolultely beautiful!

Comment: If this post was helpful, please consider to accept the answer (click on the check mark below the voting arrows). This gives me and you a small reputation boost.